# jQuery slide event order

Tags: jquery

I am displaying results of a user defined search in a div (RTab) which is hidden until the query has been started.  I wish to show the results div as soon as the search button (cmdSub) has been clicked, then issue the query.  AutoProc is a PEAR AJAX function which populates the results div.

The issue is that the div slides open after the query is complete, whereas i want it to slide open before the query is sent to the server.

```
    $("#cmdSub").click(function(){
       $('#RTab').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 100);
       AutoProc('UsrQuery');
    });
```

I have tried a number of things such as forcing UI redraw, binding my AJAX call to the show event for RTab and ensuring hasLayout is true by changing display to none and back to block.  Nothing seems to effect the order of the operation.  It is always run query then show the div!  Very frustrating!

Where am i going wrong?

Edit to show final corrected line:

```
    $('#RTab').show('slide', { direction: 'right',complete: function(){AutoProc('Query');} }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to run your query function after the animation completes, so attach your function on the `complete` event:

```
$("#cmdSub").click(function(){
   $('#RTab').show({
     complete: function(){
                 AutoProc('UsrQuery');
               },
     duration: 100
   });       
});
```

I'm not aware of any "direction" property in [`$.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) though...

Comment: Perfect - I hadn't seen the complete event.  Thanks!